# why the component is not loading in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to learn lazy loading in angular 4 .I took help from this tutorial
[How to Lazy Load Components in Angular 4 in Three Steps](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/how-to-lazy-load-components-in-angular-4-in-three-steps/)
using `loadchildren`
I tried to implement this in my example.My application is working fine but lazy load is not working .

I have four tab on header (first, second , third ,fourth) .When I click on `third` or `fourth` I didn't find any `extra network` to load module

here is [my code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yjthfb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

[image]

```
const  appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'first', component: FirstComponent },
  { path: 'second', component: SecondComponent },
 { path: 'seo', loadChildren: '../foo/foo.module#FooModule'},
  { path: '',redirectTo: '/first',pathMatch: 'full'}
];
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ,RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,FirstComponent,SecondComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you notice additional chunks when bundling your app ? (They should not be marked as `[initial]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not wrong, I tested with localhost and it renders as expected. I think stackblitz has a different way to deal with lazy loading.
[stackblitz's issue](https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/130)
[image]

Comment: will it load foo-module on both cases when user click on `third` and `forth` tab

Comment: @user5711656 it will load only first time when user click third or forth tab